# Изменение индекса

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте опять.)
Знатоки, такой вопрос: как можно заменить индекс элемента средствами js или jquery?

**Обновление**

Ну, у меня есть такой код:

```
<div>
<span id="a"></span>
<span id="b"></span>
</div>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при клике на кнопку получался такой код:

```
<div>
<span id="b"></span>
<span id="a"></span>
</div>
```

То есть менялся индекс у элемента, чтобы `#b` становился на первое место в div.

Comment: @Юра Спивак, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @Юра Спивак, это называется сортировка, только нужно знать параметры сортировки, сколько будет элементов (2 или может быть бесконечно много), тип сортировки (по какому-то признаку или поменять порядок на обратный или ещё какой-нибудь). Посмотрите вот [этот ответ][1] и указанный пример.

[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/a/10186368

Comment: Мне надо, чтобы элемент с классом active отправлялся на первое место.

Comment: Ну так подскажите, как по классу сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Юра Спивак](/users/20580/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BA),

```
var div = $('div');
$('span.active', div).prependTo(div);
```